# CSS transition not working when the starting position is display:none;

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an element that starts as `display: none` from `left: 0`. I need to show it and move it to `left: 40`. But the transition is not working. The element shows up directly at left: 40.

N.B I am not transitioning from display none to block. I am transitioning a totally different property.

Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5t43rdkb/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> N.B I am not transitioning from display none to block. I am transitioning a totally different property.

It doesn't matter whether or not you are transitioning the display property. In order for the transition to begin at all the element must already be in a state in which it can be animated. Since `display: none` suppresses box generation altogether, you can't animate a box that simply isn't there, even if you change it to `display: block` immediately in the new rule and cause it to then generate a box. In particular, properties like `position` and `left` have no meaning on a nonexistent box since, again, there is nothing to be positioned in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case. But the following doesn't work as well: https://jsfiddle.net/0ma8g3Lf/. Here, I set the element to show before transitioning.

Comment: Running the second command in a settimeout works, though: https://jsfiddle.net/u1m6xot1/

Comment: @Coffee Bite: I'm seeing the same code in both of these fiddles as the original. Make sure you saved them properly.

Comment: @Coffee Bite: I'm guessing what setTimeout does is force a redraw before kicking off the timer. So at the time the class is added the element is already shown, and the transition works as a result.

Comment: thanks very much. I have created a fiddle with all three strategies: https://jsfiddle.net/xvg8crm6/2/. I don't understand why #2 doesn't work.

Comment: AFAIK .show() simply switches the display property. It doesn't trigger a reflow itself.